# Can I limit which classes can implement an interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have:

1. `abstract class Vehicle`
2. `abstract class Car extends Vehicle` and `abstract class Truck extends Vehicle`
3. `DodgeRam extends Truck`
4. `interface Dump`

Now I want to limit `Dump` interface so that it can only be implemented by subclasses of `Truck`, without explicitly saying that `Truck implement Dump`. How can I do this?

I thought I could just change `Dump` to `interface Dump<T extends Truck>` and then say `DodgeRam implements Dump<DodgeRam>`. The problem is that nothing stops me from saying `ToyotaCamary implements Dump` and just leaving off the type.

UPDATE:

The reason I'm doing this is because I want to avoid a lot of type checking/casting. Let's say my `Truck` has an `isOffRoad` property:

```
public class Truck {
    private boolean isOffRoad;

    public Truck(boolean isOffRoad) {
        this.isOffRoad = isOffRoad;
    }

    public boolean isOffRoad() {
        return isOffRoad;
    }
}
```

Let's say I also have a `Dealership` which manages my list of `Vehicle`s:

```
public class Dealership {
    List<Truck> getTrucks() {...}

    List<Dump>getDumpers() {...}
}
```

Now I want to check the Offroad capabilities of all of my "dump trucks":

```
for (Dump dump: dealership.getDumpers() ) { 
    print dump.isOffRoad();
}
```

I don't want to have to typecheck / cast *every time*:

```
for (Dump dump: dealership.getDumpers() ) {
    if (dump instanceOf Truck) {
        print ((Truck)dump).isOffRoad();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, nothing stops you.  How could Java ever know?  How are you so sure that some smart guy with a cutting torch and a welder won't add a dumper to the back of a ToyotaCamry someday?  You can't know.

Comment: may be you posted the wrong question. Could you explain what you want to ultimately achieve?

Comment: @David updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, interfaces are always intended to provide public prototype we can not restrict the classes to implement the interfaces.

One thing you can try is.. you can define the `Dump` interface in `class Truck` and make the `Truck` class package scope instead of public and keep all the sub classes of `Truck` in the same package. so that no other class can access `Truck`  class so that no other class can implement `Dump` interface. - This is not tried but guess it works.

Answer (score 1):

interfaces are public by definition, therefore anything can implement them.  perhaps if you explained what your real goal is, there may be some other way to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

If you want only `Truck` to implement `Dump` then an `interface` is not the right tool to do that job.

Instead, you **have to** declare the methods that are present in `Dump` into `Truck` (either `abstract` or not depending if the implementation makes sense at this level).

Example:

If `Dump` is `public interface Dump { void foo(); }`

Then `Truck` should be `public abstract class Truck { public abstract void foo(); }`

That way you don't implement `Dump` and only subclasses of `Truck` can implement `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now in java 17.

```
public sealed interface TestInterface permits TestClass1, Testclass2 {

}
```